# Access denied for Service Fabric Explorer after certificate upgrade

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-service-fabric

I have been able to access Service Fabric Explorer with no problem, using a client certificate generated from Azure. The client certificate is still valid.

We recently added a new server certificate with a new thumbprint and set it to primary. (The previous server cert is secondary and hasn't been removed, if that matters.)

Now when I visit `https://<name>.centralus.cloudapp.azure.com:19080/Explorer` I get an error that varies by browser. There's no link to click through and ignore the warning.

In Edge: `The website’s security certificate is not secure. Error Code: 0`

In Chrome: `You cannot visit <name>.centralus.cloudapp.azure.com right now because the website sent scrambled credentials that Google Chrome cannot process.`

I can connect using the new certificate thumbprint via PowerShell.

Comment: How did you create the certificate? Make sure that the certificate EKU (Enhanced Key Usage) contains "Server Authentication".

Comment: Good to know. I'll have to check with our SysAdmin on that.

Comment: Sorry for the late follow up. You were right. Turns out we had left off "Server Authentication" when creating the certificate.

Comment: If you have figured it out, you could add it as answer that could help more communities who have  the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the certificate thumbprint under the cluster's client security.

[image]